# How to capture onmousedown event for a div with specific class

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-events

I have the following div:

```
<div class="signature watermarkimage" style="border: dotted currentColor; border-image: none;" data-ordinal="1">
    <div style="margin: -1em 0px 1em !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; height: 0px !important; -ms-touch-action: none;"></div>
    <canvas width="359" height="90" class="jSignature" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: currentColor; border-image: none; width: 100%; height: 90px; -ms-touch-action: none;"></canvas>
    <div style="margin: -1.5em 0px 1.5em !important; padding: 0px !important; width: 100% !important; height: 0px !important; position: relative; -ms-touch-action: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Basically want to capture the onmousedown of the div which is having signature class!
I am able to capture the onclick event handler in the following way:

```
$(document).on("click", ".signature", function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('watermarkimage')) {
        $(this).removeClass('watermarkimage');
    }
});
```

However, when I am trying to capture onmousedown in the same way, It's not propagating.
I think mostly it is due to some syntax error,any help will be highly appretiated!
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use [mousedown](https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/) event

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".signature", function () {
```

---

Also checking if the element has a class is not required. `removeClass` will remove class if the element have class if not, it doesn't do anything.

```
$(document).on("mousedown", ".signature", function () {
    $(this).removeClass('watermarkimage');
});
```

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/42a2dyyL/)

Comment: As I have mentioned, the same way its not propagating.And this class signature has some background image associated with it, not sure if thats what restricting the onmousedown action!

Comment: Sharing JSfiddle probably is restricted here.

Comment: @user2948533 No, just add the code in fiddle, save it and paste the URL here

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jemcrfeu/  here you go, here eventhough I have added the JQuery CDN, not sure why it is not identifying $. Probably due to the large name of the image url in the css.In that case you can just change the image url and see.

Comment: Any clue @Tushar? btw, I am using Jsignature api, which is creating the canvas, but dont think thats the reason of restricting onmousedown?